# Defining \absurd in prooftrees

Tags: forest, trees, logic

In https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/L4LProoftrees.pdf, a predefined expression `\absurd` is used in expressions like `close with=\absurd`.

How can this be defined?

Comment: There is no predefined `\absurd` command. How would you like it to be?

Comment: @egreg In the pdf file he writes ``%use pre-defined absurdity sign''. He uses a star like sign for absurdity in his trees.

Comment: @egreg In particular he uses ``close with=\absurd``

Comment: `\newcommand{\absurd}{{*}}`